# Is the use of "as", "to be", or "ø" interchangeable in the following context?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

Are all these expressions correct and do they carry the same meaning:

1. "Shareholders found the terms of the settlement unsatisfactory"
2. "Shareholders found the terms of the settlement as
   unsatisfactory"
3. "Shareholders found the terms of the settlement
   to be unsatisfactory"

Or:

1. "I deem her fit for that position"
2. "I deem her as fit for that position"
3. "I deem her to be fit for that position"

I often find sentences lacking either "as" or "to be" inserted between a verb and an adjective. Can it be said that spoken/informal english permits such constructions, or are they acceptable in general?

Thank you!

Comment: "as" is weird to me

Answer (score 1):

In both cases, I find the usage of "as" unsatisfactory and deem it unfit.

Options #1 and #3 are synonymous, but the "to be" in #3 is unnecessary. Use #1.

**How does this work?**

Well, basically, in this instance, "to find" is a transitive verb (or [divalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valency_%28linguistics%29), if you prefer), and can take a noun phrase argument: "I found **the cat**," or a complementized (subordinate) phrase: "the terms of the settlement [to be] unsatisfactory." In the complementized phrase, "to be" is non-finite because that's what it does.

A nominal sentence, in English, contains the copular verb "to be," and can have a noun phrase or adjectival argument.

> 1. You're a [big guy]NP.
> 2. The flag is [yellow]Adj.

Nominal sentences can drop the "to be" when embedded, like they are here, you can also say "I like my coffee hot," which "hot" obviously isn't an adjective modifying "coffee," or else it would be before "coffee," just like any other English adjective.

So basically, the underlying form of your first sentence is "Shareholders found the terms of the settlement to be unsatisfactory," and the "to be" is dropped because we can do that in English.

The second one is much the same. "Deem" can have a complementized phrase as an argument, see [Merriam-Webster's example sentence](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deem):

> "[D]eemed it wise to go slow"

But here, this isn't a nominal sentence, and you can't drop "to go."

**Tl;dr**: You don't have to say "to be" in subordinate nominal sentences, so don't use it here.

Answer (score 0):

1 and 3 are correct and equivalent in each example.  English often omits common connecting words like this, when the meaning can be easily inferred.

2 isn't precisely *wrong*, but it is an awkward formulation.  It may be found, but probably not formal writing and speech.

Comment: 2 comes across as if it's an incomplete comparison ("as unsatisfactory as my husband in bed"), which is probably why it sounds awkward.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all! When we use passive, is "as" more acceptable?
"Tolstoy is deemed by many as the greatest novelist of the 19th century"
It seems to me we can't drop "to be" or "as" here?

Comment: I disagree.  I prefer "Tolstoy is deemed by many to be the greatest novelist of the 19th century" or "Tolstoy is deemed by many the greatest novelist of the 19th century."  "As" sounds like a regional variant.